# Objective C: List all items in KeyChain Access (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm just getting started with Objective-C and I'm writing a simple application.
I try to get **all items** in KeyChain Access, but i get some problems. Items which have type "**Web form password**" from Safari, i can not get them. Any thoughts?
This is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccess forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];

NSArray *secItemClasses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                           nil];

int count = 0;
for (id secItemClass in secItemClasses) {
    [dictionary setObject:secItemClass forKey:kSecClass];
    CFTypeRef result = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, &result);

    if(status == noErr)
    {
        NSArray *arr = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)result;
        count+= arr.count;
        NSLog(@"%@",arr);
        [self showLog:[arr description]];
    }
    else if(status == errSecNoAccessForItem)
    {
        NSLog(@"errSecNoAccessForItem");
        [self showLog:@"errSecNoAccessForItem\n"];
    }
    else if(status == errSecItemNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"errSecItemNotFound");
        [self showLog:@"errSecItemNotFound\n"];
    }
}
```

(Sorry about my english)

Comment: They're (probably) `iCloud` synced passwords which can only be accessed by Safari or applications that have password sharing between the app and the app's related website.

Comment: @peter:  These items are in Local Items Keychain. And when i double click on each item, go to tab "Access Control", i see nothing to modify. Just: "Access for this item cannot be edited"...@@. Do you have any ideas for this problem ?

Comment: Is there any item listed in the 'acess group' list e.g. `com.apple.cfnetwork`? if it's not editable and this is present then it implies that the item is a icloud item.

Comment: @peter: Yes, there is a table with title: "Access group for this item: Name: com.apple.cfnetwork", but it is not editable. Can you explain what if the item is a icloud item , please ?

Comment: When the item is an `iCloud` keychain item (e.g. a safari saved password) then the API will **only** allow applications with specific entitlements to access them e.g. keychain sharing between apps, or associated domains to permit access to a subset of the username/passwords that are stored in safari.

Comment: @peter: Thank you so much :)